# Spectral function and response function

Tags: greens-functions

Could someone explain the concept of spectral function, spectral weight and linear response function? How are they useful in describing physical processes? Thanks!!

Comment: [WP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_density) and [Linear response](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_response_function). Can you focus?

Comment: @Cosmas Zachos Thanks!!